# writing a qt application in raw c++ (no qml)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm a c++ newbie(idk what counts as a newbie to be honest, but know about 95% of how c++ works, but am still new at writing programs), and have recently started messing around with GUIs.

I've made a windows application that works fine, but in addition to being a bit inconvenient at times, it frustrates me that it will only work on windows.

I'm trying qt, and after an hour of googling, and searching around their tutorials, I cant seem to find a way to write a program using raw c++ code (no qml or any stuff like that).

What I would want would be something like functions for displaying qt objects like:

```
displaybutton(xcoordinates,ycoordinates,button_object_by_reference);
```

If I'm being too general, it would be nice to know what I can specify before having this thread closed.

edit:
Okay, so http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-widgets.html is great, but is bad for me, because i still dont know the fundamentals of qt. Things like simply how the main window works for example, how classes are displayed(do i need to have a layout, or is that a bad question in the first place). the examples are good for better understanding what is implicit with how qt works, but it is still not too easy to learn the basics from(which i partially have, but its tedious looking back at the examples and trying to figure out how something that should be natural is done). So, where would i find an overview of how the environment works?

so basically, "how does qt work, but don't use qml to explain; only use c++ to explain."

Comment: You should see about doing some more research to make this question less broad. Try [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/qt/902/introduction-to-qt/12519/hello-world#t=2016083121000629169).

Comment: Probably you want QtWidgets, not QtQuick.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the widgets examples.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-widgets.html

In the few that I selected all the widgets are created natively in C++.  For instance, in the windowflags example (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-windowflags-example.html).  It shows how to make a button.

```
quitButton = new QPushButton("Button Name");
// Signal and slots are how QT handles it's callbacks
connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

For layouts you need to look into the QT Layout options.  I prefer to use designer to get a feel how the objects will look when placed, then usually write my own layout.  Again from the example, to add the button to the GUI

```
QHBoxLayout *bottomLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
bottomLayout->addStretch(); // Fill entire area
bottomLayout->addWidget(quitButton);  // Place our button in that area
setLayout(bottomLayout);  // Push layout to main GUI object.
```

Comment: you may've just answered my question, but before i spend a half an hour reading the examples in that link--will it:
1: be enough for someone who barely knows anything about writing qt to learn?
2: (to make this as clear as possible) enable me to write an entire application in 1 file?

and as a bonus:
3: will i be able to create apps that work correctly no matter the pixels per inch/screen size? This was a problem with qml.

Edit: oops, you edited your post while i was writing this comment. you may have already answered this. sry

Comment: 1.  Qt is pretty simple from principles.  If you know c++ you should be able to get Qt.  If you are new to c++, I would suggest something else for writing GUIs.
1b.  If you don't know the code why not use Qt WYSIWIG editor (designer) it is very useful
2.  It depends on how large the application.  You can always write in one file.  It may not be the best practices but there is no file limit for c++

Comment: That would require you to actually know what you are doing, so I'm guessing the answer is no. But then again, since Qt *does* allow you to solve all of those issues, the answer *may* become "yes" with a bit of studying and effort. Besides, "half an hour studying" is *nothing* - when trying to solve real problems, a week or month (or more) of studying can often be needed - get used to it.

Comment: Sorry orginal too long,
3.  There will always be a minimum.  Are you going to resize the text for all the buttons so you can keep scaling down?
3b.  QT offers method for resizing and whatnot but you may have to play out with layouts to make it work properly.

Overall I agree with Jesper, from your question it seems like you don't want to get down and dirty.  No matter what you make you are going to have to get into the code to understand it.

Comment: the main reason i commented about the size, was because i work on a surface pro, which has a pretty small screen, but an insane amount of pixels per inch. the qml code that i messed with had screwed up text size, and after i fixed it, still looked funny on a normal screen.

Answer (score 1):

To specify an exact location for a widget you can do something like this

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
button->setText("Try me");
button->move(30, 10);
button->show();
```

But it's better to use layouts so your layout will be immuned to window resizing, you can read about it here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-layouts.html